# Github: How to use SecurID desktop application for two factor authentication?

Tags: github, authentication

Can the [SecurID](http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-securid/rsa-securid-software-authenticators/ms-windows.htm) **desktop** application be used for two factor authentication on Windows or Mac?

I don't have a phone and would like to use it, and it seems like it should be possible from some posts i've read on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github uses [Time-based One-Time Password (TOTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) to generate the token while RSA SecurID generates the token based on the seed available on the RSA SecurID server. These two aren't compatible and hence you cannot use the SecurID desktop application